# Facebook Login is not working, error: Invalid Oauth access Token. it is always nil

Tags: ios, facebook, swift3, xcode8

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={NSRecoveryAttempter=<_FBSDKLoginRecoveryAttempter: 0x1740070c0>, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=190, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please log into this app again to reconnect your Facebook account., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Invalid OAuth access token., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=400, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=2, NSLocalizedRecoveryOptions=(
    OK,
    Cancel
), com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 190;
            "fbtrace_id" = AJq7xJsKJNv;
            message = "Invalid OAuth access token.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}})
```

I am facing above written error. My App contains two login schemes: 1. Facebook Login (not working) 2. Google Plus Login (working fine)

In case of facebook login: Screen is opening up, I am giving permissions to the app 
then it shows blank facebook page, just with DONE button on top. After pressing done button I receive the above mentioned error.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    // Google plus Configuration
    var configureError: NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    return true
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    let googleDidHandle = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)

    let facebookDidHandle = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)

    return googleDidHandle || facebookDidHandle
}

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey: Any]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                             sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                             annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
}
```

View Controller Code:

```
     import FBSDKShareKit
        import FBSDKCoreKit
        import FBSDKLoginKit

@IBOutlet weak var buttonOutletFacebook: FBSDKLoginButton!
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        configureFacebook()
    }   
    //MARK:- FaceBook Integrated Functions
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, openURL url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }

    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!)
    {

    FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"], tokenString: "fb_token", version: nil, httpMethod: "GET").start { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

    if error != nil{
    print(error)
    return
    }else{
    print(result)
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!){
        let loginManager: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        loginManager.logOut()
    }

    func loginButtonWillLogin(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func configureFacebook()
    {
        buttonOutletFacebook.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email"];
        buttonOutletFacebook.delegate = self
        print(buttonOutletFacebook.readPermissions)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage url scheam as below :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

   if(url.scheme!.isEqual("fb1212212121223")) {

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
            application,
            openURL: url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)

   } else {

       return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)

   }
```

}

Comment: Still not working, there is an issue with accessToken of FB